# Accessing Windows 8/10 Volume OSD Colors

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Windows has this little overlay that pops up when you change the volume

[image: Windows 10 Volume Overlay]

I'm implementing a similar notification overlay and I'd like to theme it consistently with this existing overlay without hard-coding magic values. Is there a way to access the colors, font, font color and/or positioning associated with this?

The music information appears to come from the Groove Music application and I'm not sure if that is exposed for user applications to leverage, but the volume bar is a system-wide thing that I would hope I'm able to get some basic information about.

Neither [GetSysColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371.aspx) nor [GetThemeSysColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759776.aspx) appear to have any colors that match.

Comment: It's probably based on the color that `DwmGetColorizationColor()` returns.

Answer (score 1):

That [music overlay/controller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediacontrol.aspx) is available to store applications so maybe if you port your application to UWP with the [Desktop Bridge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root) you might be allowed to use it.

It would not surprise me if the source of these colors are related to the undocumented [GetImmersiveColorFromColorSetEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37775712/3501) function in uxtheme.dll.

You can see a list of some of the color names [here](https://www.quppa.net/win8col/).