# C# console get Windows 10 Accent Color

Tags: c#, windows-10, console-application, .net-core-2.0

Is there a way in .Net Core 2.X to read the Selected Windows 10 Accent Color in a Console Application.

Most of the solution I found are UWP or WPF apps.

Too show you which color I mean, here is a picture of it:
[image]

Comment: .NET Core is cross-platform. Is there accent color on Linux or Mac?

Comment: i know it but i dont have the possibility to change the framework. So the Question is more: "Is it possible to get it. When possible how can i get it "

Comment: It's not possible in .NET Framework so I struggle to believe it'd be available in .NET Core.  A similar question has an answer (related to Win8) that might get you close if you can use .NET Framework: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660976/get-the-active-color-of-windows-8-automatic-color-theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM\ - Stores all decoration colors. So if app launched with rights to HKEY_CURRENT_USER you can read or change "**AccentColor**" property (and others in directory) or change the color code in hexadecimal notation on your own.

To get access to windows registry you need to install package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility/

Here info about package:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/windows-compat-pack/

---

The color values are stored as Registry `DWORD` (32-bit integer) values in `ABGR` order (as opposed to `ARGB` or `RGBA` order).

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

public static ( Byte r, Byte g, Byte b, Byte a ) GetAccentColor()
{
    const String DWM_KEY = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM";
    using( RegistryKey dwmKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey( DWM_KEY, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree ) )
    {
        const String KEY_EX_MSG = "The \"HKCU\\" + DWM_KEY + "\" registry key does not exist.";
        if( dwmKey is null ) throw new InvalidOperationException( KEY_EX_MSG );

        Object accentColorObj = dwmKey.GetValue( "AccentColor" );
        if( accentColorObj is Int32 accentColorDword )
        {
            return ParseDWordColor( accentColorDword );
        }
        else
        {
            const String VALUE_EX_MSG = "The \"HKCU\\" + DWM_KEY + "\\AccentColor\" registry key value could not be parsed as an ABGR color.";
            throw new InvalidOperationException( VALUE_EX_MSG );
        }
    }

}

private static ( Byte r, Byte g, Byte b, Byte a ) ParseDWordColor( Int32 color )
{
    Byte
        a = ( color >> 24 ) & 0xFF,
        b = ( color >> 16 ) & 0xFF,
        g = ( color >>  8 ) & 0xFF,
        r = ( color >>  0 ) & 0xFF;

    return ( r, g, b, a );
}
```

Comment: This will not get the correct colour if "Automatically pick an accent color from my background" is enabled.

Answer (score 8):

Starting with .NET Core 3.0 it is also possible to call UWP APIs from non UWP apps with the help of [Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts/) package.

So we can use UWP API to get accent color from .NET Core console app using:

```
var uiSettings = new UISettings();
var accentColor = uiSettings.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Accent);
```

The returned color is of type `Windows.UI.Color`, but can easily converted into for example `System.Drawing.Color`

```
Color.FromArgb(accentColor.A, accentColor.R, accentColor.G, accentColor.B);
```

Comment: +1. This should be the accepted answer because it doesn't rely on undocumented functions or messing with the registry.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 5, (Unlike with .NET Core 3.0) you don't have to reference the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` NuGet package.

Open your csproj file and update it like the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Supported platforms:
`10.0.17763.0`
`10.0.18362.0`
`10.0.19041.0`

And use it like this (From Erko's answer):

```
var uiSettings = new UISettings();
var accentColor = uiSettings.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Accent);
```

This works for desktop apps as well as Web Apps (ASP.NET Core).

In my case, I was working with Electron.NET and ASP.NET Core and it works flawlessly.

Source: [Windows Developer Blog - Calling Windows APIs in .NET5](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2020/09/03/calling-windows-apis-in-net5/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a 'couple' of calls, and it works when "Automatically pick an accent color from my background" is enabled as well

```
    public static Color GetWindowsAccentColor()
    {
        WinApi.DWMCOLORIZATIONcolors colors = new WinApi.DWMCOLORIZATIONcolors();
        WinApi.DwmGetColorizationParameters(ref colors);

        //get the theme --> only if Windows 10 or newer
        if (OS.IsWindows10orGreater())
            return ParseColor((int)colors.ColorizationColor); 
        else
            return Color.CadetBlue; 
    }

    private static Color ParseColor(Int32 color)
    {
        var opaque = true;

        return Color.FromArgb((byte)(opaque ? 255 : (color >> 24) & 0xff),
            (byte)((color >> 16) & 0xff),
            (byte)((color >> 8) & 0xff),
            (byte)(color) & 0xff);
    }
```

having WinApi class with:

```
    public struct DWMCOLORIZATIONcolors
    {
        public uint ColorizationColor,
            ColorizationAfterglow,
            ColorizationColorBalance,
            ColorizationAfterglowBalance,
            ColorizationBlurBalance,
            ColorizationGlassReflectionIntensity,
            ColorizationOpaqueBlend;
    }

    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "#127")]
    public static extern void DwmGetColorizationParameters(ref DWMCOLORIZATIONcolors colors);
```

and OS class with:

```
    public static bool IsWindows10orGreater()
    {
        if (WindowsVersion() >= 10)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    public static int WindowsVersion()
    {
        //for .Net4.8 and Minor
        int result = 10;
        var reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
        string[] productName = reg.GetValue("ProductName").ToString().Split((char)32);
        int.TryParse(productName[1], out result);
        return result;

        //fixed .Net6
        //return System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major;
    }
```

Hope this Helps
Angelo

Answer (score 1):

use `winrt-api`

**.net 5 example:**

GetAccentColor.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace GetAccentColor
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"GetAccentColor = {GetAccentColor()}");
        }

        public static Windows.UI.Color GetAccentColor()
        {
            var color = new Windows.UI.Color();
            if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsMethodPresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings", "GetColorValue"))
            {
                var uiSettings = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings();
                color = uiSettings.GetColorValue(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIColorType.Accent);
            }
            return color;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: GetAccentColor]