# How to get Windows 10 accent color?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm looking for a way to get the color that windows 10 chooses automatically depending on the background image as shown below.

[image]

I tried searching, and found

```
var color = (Color)this.Resources["SystemAccentColor"];
```

and

```
var color = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColor"];
```

but both thew an exception

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x8000FFFF
  Message=Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

Comment: I strongly suggest including the actual exception type+message in questions you post at stackoverflow. It shows that you have put some effort into diagnosing the problem, and avoids the chance to overlook something obvious.

Comment: Could you post the inner exception and stack trace as well?

Comment: @Erno de Weerd I am a pretty novice coder and am not sure what an inner exception is but I'm adding the full details now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# console get Windows 10 Accent Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840395/c-sharp-console-get-windows-10-accent-color)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get only Hex Color in this code:

```
Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColor"]
```

You have to convert it into usable color format, here is the solution.

```
var color = Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColor"];
btnTest.Background = GetColorFromHex(color.ToString());
```

And here is the converting function:

```
public static SolidColorBrush GetColorFromHex(string hexaColor)
{
    return new SolidColorBrush(
        Color.FromArgb(
        Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16),
        Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16),
        Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16),
        Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(7, 2), 16)
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the first line of code in your example is throwing an exception as mentioned above.

Comment: it works fine for me, can you show what error you are getting.

Comment: it turns out that the exception was caused by where I placed the code. It does work for me now that I put it in a good place. Thank you, and sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: This will not get the correct colour if "Automatically pick an accent color from my background" is enabled.